# Redirect URL with correct syntax

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am having some difficulty trying to format my redirect correctly.
I have the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://mooseburger.com/onlinestore/index.cgi?code=3&cat=7 
https://www.mooseburgeronline.com/categories/Clown-Costumes-/Coats%2C-Jackets-%26-Vests/
```

I know it has something to do with the % or & signs. How do you escape them?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the pattern of the RedirectMatch should be an absolute URL (like "/onlinestore/something") or an URL relative to the htaccess' location (like "onlinestore/something"). Also, the RedirectMatch pattern can't match against query strings, unfortunately. You'll need to use mod_rewrite for that, as Rekire suggested. The syntax would be something along these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bcode=(3)\b
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bcat=(7)\b
RewriteRule ^onlinestore/index.cgi https://www.mooseburgeronline.com/categories/Clown-Costumes-/Coats%2C-Jackets-%26-Vests/? [NC]
```

This also strips off the original query string. I haven't tested it, but this should get you started.

Some links:

- [The docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) are, hm, somewhat hard to read, but it's full of information. Make sure to check the [control flow diagram](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset), it helps a lot.
- [Query string cheat sheet](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/)
- [Regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for the intricacies of patterns.

And of course Google will give you hundreds of decent tutorials.

Comment: That isn't working.  I don't care if it redirects to the new category. I just need it to go from: http://mooseburger.com/onlinestore/index.cgi(there will more data here) to http://mooseburgeronline.com

Comment: not working how? Anyhow, if you don't care about the details, `RedirectMatch 301 ^/onlinestore https://www.mooseburgeronline.com/` should redirect everything starting with `/onlinestore`.